# How to send XML Data in HttpClient Post

Tags: xamarin.forms, dotnet-httpclient

I m using HttpClient in Xamarin Forms to Post below XML data which is contained in a text file to an URL.

1) this text file , ReqSAML.txt , is stored in PCL Project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
            xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
            xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>

....
.....
</s:Envelope>
```

2) I use below code to get the file and Post the XML content to a URL base on Https

```
string strURL = "https://adfs.xxx.com/adfs/services/trust/userxxxxxx";

var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();  

var assembly = typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;                
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ReqSAML.txt");

string strXML = "";       
string contentType = "application/soap+xml";


using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
{
  strXML = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

var content = new StringContent(strXML, Encoding.UTF8, contentType);

var targetUri = new Uri(strURL);

var resp = await client.PostAsync(targetUri, content);

var  soapResp = resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Is above code correctly used for Posting XML data in HttpClient?
The contentType is application/soap+xml

**The Problem encoutered**:

```
{System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: TrustFailure (One or more errors occurred.) ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
  at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-7/xamarin-android/external/mono/external/boringssl/ssl/handshake_client.c:1132
  at Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsContext.ProcessHandshake () [0x00038] in <5a97d41d36694fb19855c17429527b10>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status) [0x0003e] in <5a97d41d36694fb19855c17429527b10>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake(Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus)
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncHandshakeRequest.Run (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status) [0x00006] in <5a97d41d36694fb19855c17429527b10>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest+<ProcessOperation>d__24.MoveNext () [0x000ff] in <5a97d41d36694fb19855c17429527b10>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest+<StartOperation>d__23.MoveNext () [0x0008b] in <5a97d41d36694fb19855c17429527b10>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream+<ProcessAuthentication>d__47.MoveNext () [0x00254] in <5a97d41d36694fb19855c17429527b10>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00011] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait (System.Int32 millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00043] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait () [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.AuthenticateAsClient (System.String targetHost, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, System.Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) [0x0000d] in <5a97d41d36694fb19855c17429527b10>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.MonoTlsStream.CreateStream (System.Byte[] buffer) [0x0007b] in <5a97d41d36694fb19855c17429527b10>:0 
  at System.Net.WebConnection.CreateStream (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) [0x00073] in <5a97d41d36694fb19855c17429527b10>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0003a] in <5a97d41d36694fb19855c17429527b10>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x0000f] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__64.MoveNext () [0x002e7] in <996a681f30a44cd685a4da54e11956e2>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__64.MoveNext () [0x00478] in <996a681f30a44cd685a4da54e11956e2>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>d__49.MoveNext () [0x000ca] in <996a681f30a44cd685a4da54e11956e2>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0
```

Comment: A pretty big clue in the first line of the error: AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.

Comment: Please advise what I need to do.